# Replace special characters that appear before and after a word in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I need some help with regex that involves international characters. I have a string as followed

```
var text = "'#'Hello' Mo'nique! ''Привет марина!@¿";
```

I want special characters to be removed before and after a word but not those special characters in between like this

> Hello Mo'nique Привет марина

I have tried

```
var result = text.replace(/[`~¡!@#$%^&*()_|+\-=¿?;:'",.<>\{\}\[\]\\\/]/g,'');
```

but that will remove all the special characters and return

> Hello Monique Привет марина

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [negative look-ahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) with [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) to avoid symbols in between two words.

```js
var text = "'#'Hello' Mo'nique! ''Привет марина!@¿";

var result = text.replace(/(?!\b.\b)[`~¡!@#$%^&*()_|+\-=¿?;:'",.<>\{\}\[\]\\\/]/g,'');

console.log(result);
```

[Regex explanation here](https://regex101.com/r/Duuuwv/1)

Comment: It will remove the apostrophe in `l'école` because word boundaries in JS are not Unicode aware.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew : yup.. `é` doesn't include in `\w`

Comment: @PranavCBalan Thanks for the resources!

Answer (score -1):

use anchors to match the beginning and the end of the string

```
^[`~¡!@#$%^&*()_|+\-=¿?;:'",.<>\{\}\[\]\\\/]+|[`~¡!@#$%^&*()_|+\-=¿?;:'",.<>\{\}\[\]\\\/]+$
```

Comment: That's not what the OP wants, this doesn't remove the apostrophe/quote after `Hello`

Comment: what about using a negation
`s.replace(/([^`~¡!@#$%^&*()_|+\-=¿?;:'",.<>\{\}\[\]\\\/])[`~¡!@#$%^&*()_|+\-=¿?;:'",.<>\{\}\[\]\\\/]+([^`~¡!@#$%^&*()_|+\-=¿?;:'",.<>\{\}\[\]\\\/])/g, "$1$2");
`

Comment: Did you try it? It will remove the quote in `Mo'nique` but not the `!` after.

Comment: No, it is not. It's doing the exact oposite of OP's request.

Comment: I can get it work on a single pass, but: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZLGBOJ?editors=1111